# How to add ACL and Content-Type parameters when using skipper-s3?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, skipper

I am using skipper-s3 to upload files. I find out that all files uploaded to S3 have been set to `ACL:private` and `Content-Type:binary/octet-stream` by default. I would like to know if it is possible to set these parameters before uploading to S3.

Maybe something like this:

```
req.file('image').upload({
  adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
  key: KEY,
  secret: SECRET,
  bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  headers: {
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }
}
```

I have read the [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper-s3/issues/1), but there is still no answer. In addition, is there any way to get the `Content-Type` of files sent from client?

UPDATE: The [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper-s3/issues/1) was closed. It seems like it is a knox-mpu issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to a [pull request](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper-s3/pull/6), this is now possible.  If you don't specify a `content-type` header, it will now be guessed based on the filename.  Also note that you should use the [headers specified by the S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html); for example, to do ACL you would set the `x-amz-acl` to `public-read`.